# correspondence between abelian extensions and congruence subgroups

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I make self-study in class field theory  and I want to prove the following popular fact:

Given a modulus $\mathfrak{m}$ of a number field $K$, the map $L\mapsto ker (\phi_{L/K,\mathfrak{m}}$) is an inclusion-reversing bijection between the set of finite abelian extensions of $K$ that *admit* $\mathfrak{m}$ and the set of congruence subgroups for $\mathfrak{m}$.

An extension $L/K$ `admits` $\mathfrak{m}$ iff  $\mathfrak{m}$ is divisible by all primes that ramify in $L$ and $ker(\phi_{L/K,\mathfrak{m}})$ is congruence subgroup where $\phi_{L/K,\mathfrak{m}}$ is the Artin map.

As a result of Takagi existence theorem, the map is surjective. But I have problem about how to show it is injective.

Comment: so you're asking why field extensions of $K$ are determined by the set of primes that split completely ?

Comment: @mercio I just know that primes in the kernel of Artin map iff they split completely. Unfotunately, your hint remained  too far to me

Comment: @mercio ok I see now that my question is exactly equivalent to yours

Answer (score 1):

Your problem, in the equivalent form stated by @mercio, *precedes* class field theory. The THEOREM says: Let $L_1 , L_2$  be finite Galois extensions of a number field $K$ , and $S_1, S_2$ be the sets of primes which split completely from $K$ to $L_1 , L_2$  resp. Then $S_1 \subset S_2$ (with finitely many exceptions) if and only if $L_2 \subset L_1$. Thus $S_1 = S_2$ if and only if $L_1 = L_2$. You can find this as an exercise around the Tchebotarev density theorem in Cassels-Fröhlich (ex. 6, p. 362).